# What will be better view with JSF technology

Tags: jsf

I am using Struts Tiles with JSF to have one header, menu and footer across application. Is there any other like struts to have one header, menu and footer. Is this feature available in faceslets and what viewing technology would be better for easy development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSF you've only choice of two view technologies. The good old JSP and the improved and XHTML based Facelets. Facelets is *much* more suited to JSF than JSP. It is a view technology and template framework in one. It provides great [templating capabilities](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) and since JSF 2.0 also [composite components](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html), while JSP basically only offers the [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) for templating, so that you're forced to create *custom components* with raw Java code (which is a bit opaque and a lot of tedious work in JSF) when you want to replace a repeated group of components by a single component. If you can, I recommend to drop JSP and Tiles altogether and go for Facelets when you want to develop with JSF. If you're going for JSF 2.0 as well, it would already be a major step ahead as opposed to JSF 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

Facelets is the first choice for JSF. Your task can be easily solved with Facelets.

Comment: What about tiles. Is there any other like struts tiles which can be used with JSF